# C# - How to create an inline async Task

Tags: c#, task

As the question says, I want to know how to create an inline async Task. I tried the following (of course, `T` here is a generic abstraction that you should replace with whatever object you want):

```
var task = new Task<T>(() => new T());
var taskResult = await task;
```

However, when the taskResult line gets executed, the program just freezes - most likely because the Task isn't async. I know that I can create an async method and do the await on that, but since I'm developing unit tests, I prefer having the task definitions inline.

My question, then, is: how would I do in order to write an awaitable inline Task that doesn't freeze the program?

EDIT: The background to this is that I'm using Moq and need to mock some `async Task(...)` methods. In order to mock these, the `.Setup(...).Returns(...)` requires that I return a Task.

I tried using both the code above for inline creation, as well as an `async Task<T>` method outside the unit test method. The inline creation just froze, whereas the method ran perfectly fine. I concluded that the only real difference between these two was that the method was async and the inline code was not; hence why I thought the failure was "most likely because the inline Task isn't async".

I tried searching around for answers to this problem, but wasn't able to see anything other than `new Task<T>(() => ...)`. Hence, I asked this question in order to help others in the future who may struggle with this. Sorry for making my intents and question unclear in the start. I hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Also you can use something like this: `var taskResult = await Task.Run(() => new T());`.

Comment: @Thomas So you would construct a `T` on a thread-pool thread?

Comment: "However, when the taskResult line gets executed, the program just freezes - most likely because the Task isn't async" -> what? How did you reach that conclusion? Where is this code running (what "project type")? What framework are you targeting? Can you explain what you want to achieve? The `Task` constructor should almost never be used, by the way.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do here? there really isn't anything async *to do* with a constructor (constructors are inherently synchronous), so: why do you want this to be async? I appreciate that you're probably simplifying, but: the details *really matter*. Honestly, the correct version of the code shown is: `var result = new T();` - however, `Task.FromResult(new T())` may be of use, noting that async and threading *aren't the same thing*. Are you trying to run the constructor on another thread? if so: *why?*

Comment: The point is that you are awaiting task which never was started...

Comment: This wasn't mentioned in the post, but since I'm doing unit tests with Moq, the `.Setup(...).Returns(...)` method requires that I return a Task for any async Task method I may want to mock. You're focusing on the constructor, but that's *not the point*. The point is that I want to make an inline Task that doesn't freeze for my Mock. I thought this was more generically appliable, but from the aggravated responses, I take it that's not the case.

Comment: then: `Task.FromResult(new T())`

Comment: FWIW: I think the negative response here is because you've jumped in with a question where the intent is *really really unclear*, and then immediately posted a *really, really bizarre answer* to that unclear question; if you'd have actually made it clear what you were trying to do, people would have just said "task.fromresult", and: we'd all be carrying on with our day

Comment: @MarcGravell Okay, I didn't see that it was unclear when I posted the question. I simply thought that I could help out the community if someone else struggled with the same question, but I take it I shouldn't have done so. I edited now.

Comment: This is a case of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks! Yeah, I guess so... All I wanted to do was just help out the community in case someone else faced similar problems. I guess my biases led me to believe this was a more generic case than it was. Anyways, I got a nice answer in `Task.FromResult(..)` in the end, so thanks!

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay When you use the await keyword you get the result object from it. So T will be constructed on a Task and you get the result from the task thanks to the await keyword.

Answer (score -2):

It turns out that all I needed to do was wrap the Task with an inline async function. This creates an awaitable Task when `task()` is invoked. The way I solved it was:

```
var task = new Func<Task<T>>(async () => new T());
var taskResult = await task();
```

EDIT: As others have pointed out, you should use `Task.FromResult(new T())` in this case.

Comment: Why would you want to wrap an object construction in an asynchronous function?

Comment: As I said, I'm doing unit tests. I didn't mention this in the post, but I'm mocking (through Moq) `async Task` methods and the `.Setup(...).Returns(...) method thus sometimes requires that I return an object. Sure, I can move the object construction elsewhere, but that's beside the point.

Comment: Then why don't you just use `Task.FromResult(new T())`?

Comment: I honestly didn't know about that method. Thanks!